# Under construction message

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a website with two different store views (dutch and french). I would like to have an "under construction" message at the french site. 
http://development.safety4you.eu/webshop/?___store=fr

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you currently setting the store/website code? subdomain? subdirectory? or different FQDN?

Comment: Excuse my knowledge, i'm very new to Magento. I'm a student doing an intership and I have to fix some bugs. But I can't seem to fix this. I'm not sure what you mean. But When I log in to the backend you can switch from dutch to french. If I have to edit other files I do it trough FTP.

Comment: Sorry, I may of misunderstood your request. Are simply wanting to have the "Demo notice" shown at the top of the french store?

Comment: The dutch store is going live in a couple days. While the french one is still under construction. So we want to have a message popup or something like that which says: this page is currently under construction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I believe would be under the Admin proceed to System > Configuration. Select the French store in the drop down selector on the left top under "Current Configuration Scope", switch this to the French store view.

Proceed to Design under General, and expand the HTML Head section.  Here you'll find a "Display Demo Store Notice", select the checkbox next to the drop down that says "Use Website/Use Default" uncheck this option. Afterwards you can set the option for just the French store specifically to "Yes" while the other store views will remain "No".

After this you can customize the demo notice text via `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/notices.phtml`

Obviously you'll want to edit the `package/theme` and NOT `base/default`

Specifically the content is held at:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/notices.phtml#L44-L48

Comment: This works, but it only seems to show in the backend. How do I display this bar on the site it self?

Comment: If the design was done properly it should be displaying. You may want to take a look at your designs layout XML files and be sure that the `notices.phtml` is being included during the layout generation. Normally this is in either a `local.xml` or possibly in `page.xml` See: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml#L90

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have fixed it myself already trough the Easy site maintenace plugin.